# Is there a way to shorten the import location in Next.JS

Tags: import, next.js

**I am traditionally came from Vue and i kinda like to have the same import { } from '@/whatever
and the location seems like having many dot dot import {} from './../../from/source/file**

[image]

Please let me know if you have any installation during this kinda process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by editing the `paths` property the *jsconfig.json*. If you would like to have a shortcut for graphql, you could do this for example:

// jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "graphql/*": ["graphql/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Your `import` statement would so shorten to this:

```
import { ADD_USER_MUTATION } from "graphql/mutations"
import { GET_USER_BY_EMAIL_QUERY } from "graphql/queries"
```

This only works if on the *graphql* folder is in the root directory. Read more about this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

Comment: thanks for the answer and i found similar answer using by creating // jsconfig.json                          {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}                                                                                                                                                            This way i can import  {} from '~/file/file'

Comment: Whatever works best for you. Happy to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible to do that in Next.js, it is explained in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) and no installation during the process

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answer i kinda like to have ~/file/file so i created this short configuration

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```